# Images load up super slow in collectionview and which is also making my scrolling freeze up and run slow

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Issue:** 6-7 Images load up super slow in collectionview. Takes 6 secs to bind with collectionview, another 3 secs to load up images when scrolling down. bc of this its also making my scrolling freeze up and run slow.

according to my logs:

`[Choreographer] Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. [Choreographer] Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

i been looking on google for a week now and according to other post online, I already have done the following but nothing seem to be working. so i am not sure what is the issue. (not like i am displaying 50 images here)

1. Clean up UI code
2. Cache Images (this plugin says itss load up images 50% faster. I dont even wanna imagine how long they will load without this plugin :(

**I think issue is**: after doing some debuging. i found out this line takes less than 1 sec `var getData = await CarServices.DisplayAllCar();` but this line takes 5 secs `CarList.AddRange(getData);`. after than when you are scrolling down, i noticed some of the images are still loading up.

so this tells me issue isnt with my database but binding with collectionView

Here i am creating a collection,

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding CarList}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectedItem="{Binding ItemSelectedEvent, Mode=TwoWay}"
                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame CornerRadius="15" HasShadow="True" Padding="0">
                <Grid>
                    <ff:CachedImage  Grid.Row="0"
                        Source="{Binding StoreImagePath}" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding CarColor}"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                           TextColor="white" ></Label>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

following code, will bind to collectionview

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<CarModel> CarList { get; set; }

public async  void OnAppearingViewModel(Page sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    LoadDataFromDatabaseToList();
}

//Load Data from database into list 
public async void LoadDataFromDatabaseToList()
{
        CarList.Clear();
        // takes less than 1 sec to run this line
        var getData = await CarServices.DisplayAllCar();
       //takes 5-6 secs
        CarList.AddRange(getData);
}
```

following code will: Open Camera, Take Photo, Crop Image, Save in Cache Folder, re-save in app data folder and lastly save image-path in database (used to open image in collectionview from app data folder)

```cs
new ImageCropper()
{
    PageTitle = "Crop Photo",
    AspectRatioX = 6, // x
    AspectRatioY = 4, // y
    CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle, //Cropt shape
    SelectSourceTitle = "Select source",  // Pop up Title
    TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",       // Popup - 1st option 
    PhotoLibraryTitle = "Photo Library", //Popup - 2nd option
    Success = (imagePath) =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            //Step#0: auto saves image in: cache folder
            //Step#0: imagePath = get path of image
            //Step#1: re-save same image to app data direcctory folder
            ReSave_Image_To_AppDataFolder(imagePath); 
        });
    }
}.Show(this);

//Save in database
await CarServices.InsertCar(mycolor, imagePath);
```

Comment: How many images are you displaying?

Comment: Have you considered removing `Clear` and using `ReplaceRange` rather than `AddRange`?

Comment: If you comment out `ReSave_Image_To_AppDataFolder` does it solve the speed issue?

Comment: `LoadDataFromDatabaseToList()` call should be with `await` keyword

Comment: i am displaying few 6 to 7 pictures. I dont have await on `LoadDataFromDatabaseToList` but i have it on `await CardServices.DisplayAllCar();` which is inside that method.

Comment: `ReSave_Image_To_AppDataFolder` yes tried that but still same thing. I didnt tried adding `ReplaceRange` that but i can try.

Comment: but still i think android phone should be able to handle 6 to 7 images inside collisionview, right or no? no like i am building instagram with tons of images lol

Comment: If you start use `await`, you should continue use it everywhere where it's possible. I think, your compiler gives you a warning about `OnAppearingViewModel lacks await call`.  See. for example, this article:  https://www.anthonysteele.co.uk/AsyncBasicMistakes

Comment: just finsihed reading it, yes did added it but no difference for loading ime

Comment: after doing some debuging. i found out this line takes less than 1 sec `var getData = await CarServices.DisplayAllCar();` but this line takes 5 secs `CarList.AddRange(getData);`. after than when you are scrolling down, i noticed some of the images are still loading up. so this tells me issue isnt with my database but binding with colliionview

Comment: i am having same issue, the plugin u using, its saves image size to 3000x3000. that could be causing your issue

Comment: The loading, cropping and saving of the images, should be decoupled and run on a different thread than the main UI. saving could happen item by item or when all of them have been loaded. Maybe you should consider a cache to avoid loading, cropping and saving an item that already was proccesed

Comment: Please share the source code for `DisplayAllCar`.

Comment: Have you tried to use `ObservableCollection` instead of `ObservableRangeCollection` ?

Answer (score 0):

seem like your plugin saves image way too large. i had this same issue and took month to find out. anyways I fixed it by re-sizing it. see below

```
 private async void ReSizeImage(string filePath, string filename)
    {
            // re-size image
            var stream1 = await ImageService.Instance.LoadFile(filePath)
                                .DownSample(width: 600).AsPNGStreamAsync();

            // Save re-sized image
            using (var stream2 = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                await stream1.CopyToAsync(stream2);
     
}
```